# Are there celestial bodies that are about as far away as the Sun?

Tags: the-sun, distances, asteroid-belt

Just curious. The Sun is 500 light seconds away from the Earth depending on time of the year. The orbit of Mars is about 50% as far as the Sun, the orbit of Vesta about 150%. Is there / Are there celestial bodies inbetween with about the distance of the Sun, their orbit around 93 million miles far from the Earth?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asteroids with an orbit of between 1.8 and 2 Au (So their closest approach is is about the same distance to the Earth as the Earth is to the sun) are called Hungaria group asteroids, named after 434 Hungaria.

Hungaria itself has an orbit of 1.94 AU, so would be a good example of body. Such asteroids are rather rare. There is a gap in the asteroid belt caused by Jupiter at 2.06 AU, and tighter orbits tend to be disrupted by Mars.

Of course, at any given time, the actual distance to Hungaria will vary between about 1 and 3 AU